# Error: Type Mismatch during loading class in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Objective:** I would like to add class in label during loading of form in access.

**Problem:** When i tried to run the process it will give error 'Run-time Error 13': Type mismatch

[image]
[image]

**Cod In **MyLabelClass**:**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents LabelControl As MSForms.Label

Private Sub LabelControl_Click()
    MsgBox "Label name: " & LabelControl.Name & vbNewLine & "Label Tag: " & LabelControl.Tag
End Sub
```

**Code in my Form:**

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyClickableLabel As New MyLabelClass

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set MyClickableLabel.LabelControl = Me.Label2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Access forms and their controls are **not** `MSForms`.

Declare your variable like this:

```
Public WithEvents LabelControl As Access.Label
```

Comment: Declaring it as `Access.Label` does not require the `LabelControl.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"`. Plain `Label` does though. Interesting.

Comment: Indeed interesting, thanks. I hadn't tested the actual click event. @KostasK.